# Connecting old CD-RW drive with an odd 40 pin connection to raspberry pi

Tags: gpio, usb, hard-drive

**QUESTION**

So I recently got my hands on an old computer from around 2000 and it didn't work so I decided to take it apart and try to make something a bit useful with the parts. Inside there were 2 cd drives, both take a 40-pin cable with one pin missing (image 1) and also that pin's hole is blocked in the cable. (image 2) (So I guess its really a 39-pin connector)

**one cd drive says CD-ROM (Image 4) on it and one says CD-RW (Image 3) if this could work with the CD-RW drive so that I could Write disks too then that would be ideal**

I would like to figure out how to either plug the thing straight into the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi or find a way to connect certain pins to the wires inside of some sort of USB data cable or something like that so that I could plug it into a USB port on my raspberry pi. (any type of cable would work for this but my parents might get mad if I destroy another HDMI cable so maybe that's not a good idea.)

(I would probably prefer the USB option if possible because then I could potentially burn from one DVD to another or something)

Also, keep in mind that I am not very experienced at coding and can only code basic stuff in python so if I have to code something on my own it probably wouldn't work.

I would appreciate any answers on the subject and if you were wondering why I would like to do this it's because I don't have any devices that can read or write disks in my house and it could be useful for something at some point.

The tech I have available is a windows laptop, a raspberry pi 4 model B with 4 gigs of ram and I guess an iPhone and Samsung phone but I don't see how that's important. i also have a variable bench power supply that goes from 0-30 volts and 0-10 amps dc.

Hopefully this was detailed enough because normal stack overflow posts arent and it's very annoying and thanks in advance to anyone who helps me :) keep in mind that I'm a kid and dont have very much money and would like to do this without any sort of buying stuff but its ok if I have to spend a little bit.

**IMAGES**

**Pins on drive**

[image: pins on drive]

**pins on cable**

[image: pins on cable]

**CD-RW drive**

[image: Cd RW drive]

**CD-ROM drive**

[image: Cd rom drive]

Comment: USB to PATA adapters used to be common but since SATA drives become ubiquitous may be hard to find. The real challenge is the 12V these old drives require.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, surprisingly, it is possible to hook up an old IDE device to a Pi.
Look here https://github.com/manawyrm/pata-gpio for details on how to setup hardware and software to do it.